# Keyboard shortcut to stop an Automator service (Quick Action)

Tags: automator, services

I have a `Watch Me Do` automator service / quick action that uses pause and a long running loop to repeat the actions when I am away.

I have created a keyboard shortcut for the service

But since it uses mouse events and is long running, at some point I want to use a keyboard shortcut to stop it when I return to my computer and want to resume my activities.

How would I achieve this? Any alternative workflows/suggestions would also be welcome

**Edit:**

My goal is to record a "watch me do" action involving opening an application and doing some clicks and keep repeating it (with delays) until I want it to stop.

I should be able to stop and start this "service" using a keyboard shortcut.

**Edit 2 (Details):**
Mac Version: macOS Big Sur (Version 11.3.1)

Here is an example service I created

1. Watch Me Do

   Click Mail in the Dock

   Click the "fill in title" toolbar button

   Click the "fill in title" button
2. Pause

   for 60 seconds
3. Loop

   Loop automatically Stop after 60 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

- Create a new **Automator** *Quick Action*.

  - **Workflow receives [no input] in [Mail]**
- Add a **Run Shell Script** *action*.

  - **Shell: [/bin/zsh]**
  - **Pass input: [to stdin]**
- Add the following *command* to the **Run Shell Script** *action*:

  - `pkill -9 com.apple.automator.runner`

**Notes:**

In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** I assigned it a *keyboard shortcut* of: **⌃⌥⌘Q**

I tested this in **macOS Catalina**, as I do not have **Mail** setup under **macOS Big Sur**, and it work for me without issue.

This will *kill* all **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* that are running.

Answer (score 1):

I believe cmd + . should do the trick.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and explain why you think this will help. What does the key combo do? Also, please take the [tour] to better understand how SE works.